# Cannot do a merge

Tags: tfs, merge

I have a merge candidate that i cannot merge to a branch from source branch. There are no differences between two branches in the files affected but I cannot undo the changeset.

I even tried to perfrom a 'no-merge' merge from command lines of tfs. Still no success.

Every merge attempt says "there are no changes to merge".

I just want to get rid of this merge candidate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command line option that will let you remove a changeset from the candidates to merge.

The command line:

```
c:\projects>tf merge /discard /version:C137 branch1 branch2 /recursive
```

should do the trick. If it doesn't I read a couple places that say sometimes you have to use /baseless with this to get rid of changesets that won't go away.

For more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx

Comment: As i mentioned I tried command line /discard merge. It does not work. I will try to do a /baseless.

Comment: Because it can't find any differences I think the /baseless is what will help.

Comment: And for me `/version:C137~C137` did it.